# Concrete 5 dynamically named areas

Tags: php, concrete5

I have inherited a concrete 5 project and am debugging why certain 'areas' on the page do not show up the 'inline editing' feature.

The version is 5.5.1.

Essentially there is a page where it lists some items and each item has some div's to contain some information about each one, e.g name, description:

```
<div class = "description"></div>
```

The issue is that only one of the description elements is editable - I have worked out that this could be because the 'area' is name statically thus:

`<div class = "description">
    $a = new Area('Property Details');
    $cont = Page::getByID($page->getCollectionID());
    $regexMatchThis = $a->display($cont);
    </div>`

So therefore there is only one area called 'Property Details' allowed to be editable. Am I ciorrect, and how can I name the area so that it reads the correct data but can be uniquely named so that it can be editable?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pekka is correct, but I'm hesitant to litter the answer discussion with another (long) explanation.

Areas are dynamic based on the name. Thus, "Property Details 1" is different than "Property Details 01".

You could do something like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   $a = new Area('Property Details ' + $i); 
   $a->display();
}
```

And you'd get 10 sequentially named "Property Details x" areas, from 1 - 10.

Let's say you add content block to them. As long as they remain with the exact same names, then the blocks will work as expected. You could even change the first line to:

```
for ($i = 10; $i >= 1; $i--) {
```

In that case, you'd get the areas named sequentially downward (10, 9, 8...) and C5 would keep the content blocks in their original areas -- so they'd all be in reverse.

But let's say you do:

```
for ($i = 11; $i <= 20; $i++) {
```

Now you get 10 areas (11, 12, 13...), and all are blank. The content blocks have basically disappeared. You can create new content blocks if you want. But then go ahead and put the original loop back in (1, 2, 3...). Your original content blocks are back -- just like before.

This really long explanation just goes to show that C5 creates a block based on a name, and that name becomes the key. It can be anything. You can base it on the page name, or dynamically generate it, or whatever. You just can't change it once it's been created (if you don't want to "lose" the blocks).

But... I'll agree with Pekka again here... you probably don't want to do this. Not knowing your goal, you're creating (or prolonging) a very brittle solution that's difficult to maintain. Pekka suggests creating subpages for each property, then you can use a page list block to "pull" the applicable attributes. Or, if you don't want to create separate pages, use Jordan's Designer Content block -- http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/designer-content/ . Have a single area ("Property Details"), and add a block for each property. Much easier to delete, reorder, etc.

**Edit to address Sphere's first two questions:**
Adding blocks to areas is really straightforward. As long as the areas don't have duplicate names, you click on it just like you've tried previously, and add a block. I'm not sure what block type your particular site needs -- that's specific to your site. It might just be a *Content* block, or maybe a *Pagelist* block with a particular template, where the previous developer set it up to  "list" one page per block instance, per area (which would be REALLY weird, but you never know...). Or, maybe it's a block type created from the *Designer Content* block which I mentioned earlier. Poking around on the existing blocks should give you an idea. Also, I find that sometimes they write out some identifying ID in the HTML. So, the source is something like .

As for your code sample: Yes, $cont is page. The code that Pekka and I provided ($a->display()) basically does:

1. Initialize an area called 'Property Details' (or 1 or 2 or whatever). This is the key, as discussed.
2. Display it, defaulting to displaying it "for" the current page. This is different than "on" the current page. It will always display on the current page... what you pass as an argument to ->display() is more like "the page that the area should be pulled from". So if you could theoretically pass $thePageObjectForPropertyOnMainStreet, and it would display that page's 'Property Details' area. Using $cont is unnecessary. As it creating it (it already exists).
   But... now that I think of it, that might be what he tried to do. $cont might have been a reference to individual property pages. Those pages *might* have an area called "Property Details", and this his loop serves to "pull the area" from those pages. But, $cont would have looked different.
   You can hardcode this by doing something like $cont = Page::getByID(x);, where x is the cID for a property page, which has an area called "Property Details". You can get the cID in the URL after you edit and save it.

Comment: Thank you. It seems the bit I'm missing is the 'add a block to an area' bit. It is not obvious from the new Area() code, how that link is made. Essentially I'm looking to support a system built by another developer and the client isn't willing for us to spend any time/cost on apparent bugs. A quick/dirty solution would be to make the 'areas' dynamically named, but I'm not sure where these link to the blocks - I cannot see a block called 'Property Details', or similar. I'll admit I'm a little confused, but thank you for your patience.

Comment: $cont = Page::getByID($page->getCollectionID()); $regexMatchThis = $a->display($cont); Is this $cont variable not a 'page' as you mention?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, that code seems to be defining only one area (and doing some unrelated things in between).

If the second area you desire doesn't exist yet, just make up a second one like so:

```
 <div class = "description">
   <?php
    $a = new Area('Some more info'); 
    $a->display(); `
    ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the area needs to be part of a php while loop, so the area 'Property Details' needs to be on the page for each property. Therefore the 'area' will be present in each pass of the loop and by the same name. However, I am assuming because it is defined (more than once) as  'Property Details', rather than, say, 'Property Details x' - that this is why the edit function is only working on the first 'Property Details' area? What I tghink I am asking, is can the 'area' have a dynamic 'name' and still reference the appropriate 'area' content?

Comment: @Sphere yeah, you'd have to name the boxes `property details 1`, `2` and so on. But is this for a potentially endless list of properties? If that's the case, this approach isn't going to make you happy: what if you need to delete property no. 5? In that case, you could e.g. use sub-pages and fetch the data from them... that's more complex though

Comment: Yes, correct. It's how it was set up by the original developer. I take it I am correct in my assumption as to why the edit feature is not working is because there is an area on the page that is repeated? Is there no way to dynamically reference an area to make it editable uniquely?

Comment: @Sphere yeah, it looks like that's the reason why it doesn't work - it's just one Area and you can't have it in there multiple times. Maybe it used to work differently in older versions of C5, no idea.... I don't completely grasp your last sentence, can you clarify?

Comment: There's multiple instances of the area that's called 'Property Details'. Only one of these 'areas' is editable when logged in (i.e has a red outline around it so that one can edit it inline). I assume this is because each area has to have a unique name - so having it in a while loop with the same name each time will cause this issue?

Comment: So my question is really, can i name the 'area' dynamically - e.g: 'Property Details'.$id (where id is the instance of the item in the loop). It doesn't seem to work this way.

Comment: @Sphere sure, you should be able to do that.  `$a = new Area("Property". $i);` should work fine. It's just not very flexible - what if you need to delete propery no. 4, or add another between no. 2 and no. 3?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work. It seems to rely on the area being called 'Property Details' in order to show any data in there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Pekka, but I think this problem may not be solved by adjusting the 'area'. I am not familiar with C5, so if there is an easy/quick/dirty way to handle this, great, otherwise, again, thank you for your time :)

Comment: @Sphere you can create Areas on the fly. If you do `$a = new Area("Property5"); $a->display()` this should give you a new rectangular area which you can fill with content. If you add 10 areas named `Property1`-`Property10`, you should get 10 empty containers which you can fill. Is that not happening for you? Or are you looking to display *existing* data?

Comment: If I change the name of the area, for example as you suggest above, then the content disappears, so I assume that the content is tied to the name of the area somehow?

Comment: @Sphere yes, that's the expected behaviour. If that's a problem, then I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here?

Comment: Ok, then in that case I don't understand how an 'area' is tied to it's content.

Comment: @Sphere automatically. If you create an Area with the name `xyz`, it will automatically show up as editable; if you put stuff in it, it will be stored under `xyz`.

Comment: In your above answer, then, for example, where would the content for the area called 'Some More Info' get set?

Comment: @Sphere do you mean "where physically", or "where in the context of the CMS"? If the latter - the page you're on will get a new database entry named `Some More Info`, and the Area's content will be in there (very roughly speaking)